# Как писать приложения для Verifone?

Tags: android

Можно ли писать приложения для Verifone VX820 или аналогичного устройства (не связанные с оплатой) и запускать их на имеющемся у меня устройстве, без публикации их где-либо или их можно запускать только на эмуляторе?

Comment: Можно. А почему тэг андроид? Они на андроиде, что ли?

Comment: Вот [тут](https://developer.verifone.com/docs/overview/download-the-sdk) указан Android Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Теоретически можно писать приложения для абсолютно любого устройства. Практически вам для этого потребуется среда разработки, SDK и знание, как загрузить собственное приложение на устройство. К счастью, Verifone идет вам на помощь и предлагает целый портал для разработчиков: [Verifone Developer Central](https://developer.verifone.com/docs/overview/get-started).

Там можно скачать SDK, почитать как что делать, наверняка и пара примеров найдется.

Comment: Дело в том, что на их сайте ничего не написано про загрузку приложений в устройство, зато написано про прохождение лицензирования и загрузку приложений в marketplace и запуск в эмуляторе.

Comment: Вот описано как загрузить на терминал - [Setting up the Carbon Test Terminal](https://developer.verifone.com/docs/develop/develop-terminal-apps/test-terminal-and-app-testing).